# TinyMCE for django

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE Editor or any other text editor in django for textarea. I am having a really hard time finding a good examples or tutorials. found one video on youtube but it was too fast for me to understand. any guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for ali project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Django settings for corating project.

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

print 'BASE_DIR ',BASE_DIR
print 'PROJECT_DIR ',PROJECT_DIR
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-=153zwy^8$sz%gsw#kb377pp@r3wmcer(4tc$j-h4(^3s+zw+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ali.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ali.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static_root')
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "js/tiny_mce")

print "TINYMCE_JS_ROOT  ",TINYMCE_JS_ROOT
print "TINYMCE_JS_URL   ",TINYMCE_JS_URL


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/home/hussain/django/ali/ali/templates/',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE


class FlatPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))

    class Meta:
        model = FlatPage
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from page.forms import FlatPageForm 

def HomePage(request):
    form = FlatPageForm()
    print " form :: ",form
    return render_to_response('HomePage.html',{'form':form})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from ali.views import HomePage
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ali.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', 'ali.views.HomePage' ),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls') ),

)
```

Error :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/home/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tinymce')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/hussain/django/ali/ali/views.py" in HomePage
  6.     print " form :: ",form
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/encoding.py" in <lambda>
  60.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  103.         return self.as_table()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  223.             errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  186.                     'field': six.text_type(bf),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  425.         return self.as_widget()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
  475.         return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
  572.         options = self.render_options(choices, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
  528.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
  1044.             for obj in self.queryset.all():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  96.         self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  710.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  781.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  450.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /home/
Exception Value: no such table: django_site
```

Comment: Well the traceback shows that you have not probably created database some kind of database table, as it clearly states: No such table: django_site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is project for that: 
https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce

Basically you download the projcect, download tinymce. Add tinymce files to your template and then follow the config tutorial in django-tinymce project.

Comment: Yitsaeb I need a little help.
I am following the documentation but here http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#python-code getting an error reading `Exception Value:  

name 'ModelForm' is not defined` do you have any idea ?

Comment: Not without seeing more code from you. Do you have the imports that this code requires in your code. What this error refers to is that you have not imported forms.ModelForm from django.

Comment: Odif I have Updated my question.

Comment: This update does not help anybody much. If you are getting errors, then you should post complete error message. You could also remove this print from view, as it does nothing. Also, render_to_response, should include context_instance, otherwise context processors will not be used